# How to build ios application using Phonegap framework on windows OS.

Tags: ios, cordova

I have allready build an android application using Phonegap framework, I need to develop the application for ios also using windows OS.I know that for ios we need XCode that runs only on mac machine,but is there any way to do it on windows ( as I can't afford Mac machine) ?

I searched for various options,few of them are:

1.Install mac os using VM ware.
2.Use MacinCloud Service.

I don't know what are the advantages and disadvantages of each of them, please suggest what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use PhoneGap Build. Just upload the html/js/css/config with specified plugin as zip and build it online. Unfortunatelly you will not be able to use custom plugins, only specified on the [PhoneGap Build site](http://build.phonegap.com/).

Comment: My android app uses main activity java file to show splash screen and progress bar, also thie method:- super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());      will not run on ios, so will the phonegap build automatically takes care of it?

Comment: You can control splash screen via plugins, get rid of progress bar :) and i don't know about super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl()) - you can try to do it via javascript. But phonegap Build is the only way to build iOS version without xcode.

Comment: ok Ivarik,thanks for your suggestion but I have not aksed to do without Xcode, I am asking to build ios apps without using mac machine?

Comment: Is there no one who can help me regarding this?